# Evolute of pseudosphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

The evolute of a tractrix meridian is known to be a catenary.. I wanted to search for the evolute of a pseudosphere meridian ( the catenary is a tractrix  evolute special case ) as evolute superset of curves, but could not find any.

I formed a figure by erecting normals on special hyper pseudosphere meridian to get:

[image: PS(hyper)_Evolute]

However am not sure if this shape is correct.. especially the jump of radius of curvature at some points and the meaning of self intersections.

Request for comments ( even qualitative it helps), and to point me to available literature sources... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Error in plot corrected.

Looking for references. Thanks.

[image: ErrorCorrected]